# understanding python function; returned value

Tags: python

hi guys I need help understanding python functions! can the returned value of a python function be from a dictionary? also, is it really necessary for a python function to have a returned value?

Comment: do you have an example for "from a dictionary"?

Comment: Shows us at least one example to elaborate the issues you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a dictionary from a function as

```
>>> def f():
...   d = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
...   return d
... 
>>> 
>>> f()
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

You can also return a single value from a dictionary

```
>>> def f():
...   d = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
...   return d[1]
... 
>>> f()
'a'
```

When you don't return a value from a function, it is considered as `None`

```
>>> def f():
...   d = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
...   return
... 
>>> returned_value = f()
>>> print(returned_value)
None
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks! so to clarify, it is not necessary that a python function must have a returned value and that it is also not necessary for a python function to have input arguments then?

Comment: Yes, a function **may** have no arguments and no return values. It will work absolutely fine.

Comment: also no need to include the `return` keyword at all, python functions will return `None` in that case too

Comment: That was to just show that function can be returned with no return values. return keyword can be used before the function ends to come out before.

Comment: Unless your function doesn't need to interact with anything, it is almost always good practice to be accepting arguments and returning values from functions. Certainly, do no use global variables. The other alternative is to use a class.